# Differential calculus - Derivative of √x - Geometric intuition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why we divide the small difference 'd√x' by the difference in area 'dx' Where  we normally divide the difference in area by the small difference ?[image]

My huge confusion is, when we try to find the derivative of x^2 we **divide the difference in area 'dx^2' by the small difference dx** -> **dx^2 / dx** . But while i try to find the derivative of √x, i get a correct answer only when i **divide the small difference by the difference in area** -> **d√x / dx** ??

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I didn't understand what are you asking about. Please type the last part of your question and be clear in what you are asking about

Comment: What i'm asking here is, "Why the derivative of √x is d√x/dx where d√x is the a small difference & dx is the difference in area ? Whereas the derivative of x^2 is dx^2 / dx where dx^2 is the difference in area & dx is the small difference."

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find the rate of change in the side of a square relative to the change in area.  So you have a division, similar to finding other instantaneous rates of change.

If $x$ is the area and $s=\sqrt{x}$ the side then you are looking at what happens when you increase the area slightly.  Writing $d\sqrt{x}$ at this stage may be more confusing than something like $\delta s$

You get the change in area to be $\delta x = 2 s \, \delta s + (\delta s)^2 \approx 2 s \, \delta s$ when $\delta s$ is small compared with $s$.  So in terms of relative changes $\dfrac{\delta s}{\delta x} \approx \dfrac{1}{2s}$.  Throughout this process $\delta s$ and $\delta x$ are small

You then take the limit, substitute back  and get the derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but d√x is the small difference & dx is the change in area isn't it ? Then, how can we divide the small difference d√x by the change in area dx ?

Comment: I do not like the notation but your $d\sqrt{x}$ is the small change in the side while $dx$ is the small change in area and you are trying to find the rate of change in the side in terms of area. Rather like velocity being the rate of change of position in terms of time

Answer (score 1):

When talking about derivatives here, we will be studying the variation of a certain function($x^2$, $\sqrt{x}$, ...) with respect to the variable $x$. In other words, we will be studying how the function changes, according to a very small variation $dx$ on $x$.

That is $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ or in your examples $\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ and $\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx}$.

It is not a rule to divide what you call  the "difference in area" by the "small difference" to get the derivative. If you put $\frac{dx}{d\sqrt{x}}$ you'll be studying the variation of $x$ according to a small variation of $\sqrt{x}$ and thats not the definition of the derivative you're talking about.